# Formation of meniscus

Tags: surface-tension, fluid-statics

If molecules at the surface of a liquid have higher energy and want to minimise the surface area, then why is a mensicus formed which of course increases the surface area?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/81163/2451

Answer (score 4):

The reason is that the gas-liquid surface area is not the *only* surface area that is minimized. The total energy of the system (including only surface energies) is given by:
$$E=\gamma_{lg} A_{lg}+\gamma_{sg} A_{sg} + \gamma_{sl} A_{sl} $$

Formation of a meniscus as opposed to a flat surface indeed increases $A_{lg}$, but, due to volume conservation, it lowers $A_{sg}$ or $A_{sl}$ depending on whether the meniscus is curved upward or downward respectively. If for example $\gamma_{sg}$ is very large then it can by energetically favourable to increase $A_{lg}$ in order to decrease $A_{sg}$ and lower the total energy. In this way you can in fact derive the [contact angle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contact_angle) that will result in the minimum energy state.